# php doesn´t interpret my hex characters as hex

Tags: mysql, code-injection

I am trying to understand a mysql injection not working as expected.
I have a php script that does a login based on username and password supplied on a webpage. The query string looks like this:

`$querystr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertbl WHERE user='$user' and pass='$pass'";`

Username and password are escaped before they are used in the querystr above. This means any apastroph(single quote) is escaped as well.
I found a blog describing this very issue here: [mysql_escape_string-the-charset-vulnerability](http://www.gosecure.it/blog/art/483/sec/mysql_escape_string-the-charset-vulnerability/).

I tried to replicate what´s explained on that blog, but when I supply hexadecimal characters for user or pass on the website, php somehow doesn´t interpret them as hex it seems.

When I enter for the username on the webpage(password empty):

> user\xbf\x27

the query logged by MySQL is:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertbl WHERE user='user\xbf\x27 or 1=1--' and pass=''

So, to me it looks like the hexadecimal characters are not interpreted as such.

For some more debugging, I created the following php script, which I ran on the server:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=gbk');
$hex="\xbf\x27";
echo mysql_escape_string($hex);
?>
```

The output is:

> �\'

Does anybody have an idea why it might not work for me?

Thank you

Comment: this looks like a pure PHP problem and not a SQL injection problem - stackoverflow might be a better place to ask?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `$hex="\xbf\x27";` in a php script, PHP parses it and stores the string formed by the hexadecimal bytes `BF 27`.

When you type `\xbf\x27` in a web page, it is sent verbatim to the server, so the query ends up with the literal text «\xbf\x27».

The way to exploit it would be to enter that character in the browser (eg. changing your browser encoding to iso-8859-1 and pasting a `¿`), or sending a fake HTTP request where you directly insert in the wire any byte you wish. If you are performing the injection through HTTP GET, there's an easy way to insert which is using  %-escapes, ie. "`&user=user%bf%27%20or%201=1--&pass=`".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Now the string arrives at the php interpreter as supposed. The issue is now, that the query string still contains �\' instead of _<kanji>'_

Comment: The string contains the bytes `BF 5C 27`in both cases. The difference is that if interpreted as gbk, BF 5C is interpreted as a single character, and thus won't escape the single quote. Try manually changing the encoding in the browser to Simplified Chinese (in addition to GBK, GB18030 will also work). You can even test it on this page.